# Expected values from discrete joint functions

Tags: probability

I know how they go with continuous functions, but I don't know how they work with discrete functions. So for example I have a sample space of {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)} with density functions of f(1,2)=1/2, f(3,4)=1/4, f(5,6)=1/4. How can I find E(X), E(Y), E(X+Y) and E(XY)? This has to be significantly simpler than it is with continuous functions, but I can't wrap my head around it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In the discrete case, the density function function $f$ is defined by $\forall x \in E, f(x) = \mathbf{P}(X =x)$

Comment: How are exacly defined the random variables X and Y ?

Answer (score 0):

I will start with E(X+Y) and E(XY). Given that f(x,y) are directly stated, E(X+Y) is simply (x+y)*f(x,y) for each pair. E(XY) is found in a similar fashion, that is, XY*f(x,y).

E(X) is derived from the marginal distribution of x. In this case, since the probability of x = 1 is 1/2 , x = 3 is 1/4 and x = 5 is 1/4 (given from the first number in each pair). It is possible to find E(X) easily. E(Y) can be found in a similar fashion.

Your case is very simple for marginal distributions because it doesn't need to consider multiple values of the same x attached to different values of y (e.g. (1,2) (1,3) etc). Let me know if you need help solving that example too.